# MySQL query slow on localhost - mostly network duration

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running a very simple query on an indexed column in a 20 mln row table.

```
select * from prvol where date = '20100203';
```

It takes about 22 seconds.  I am new to sql, but think that an indexed column should be faster than this.  There is no memory issue.  Also, the output says the time is mostly in network.  I'm running the query on the same machine the server is on.

```
/* 0 rows affected, 6,882 rows found. Duration for 1 query: 0.828 sec. (+ 21.438 sec. network) */
```

What does that network time mean?  Would you expect this query to run faster?

#### EDIT: as requested, here is some output.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM prvol WHERE date = '20100203';
"id","select_type","table","type","possible_keys","key","key_len","ref","rows","Extra"
"1","SIMPLE","prvol","ref","Index 1","Index 1","4","const","6881","Using where"
```

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE prvol;
"Table","Create Table"
"prvol","CREATE TABLE `prvol` (
  `exch` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ticker` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `open` float unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `high` float unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `low` float unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `close` float unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `vs` float unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `aclose` float DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `Index 1` (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1"
```

Comment: Please post the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM prvol WHERE date = '20100203'` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE prvol`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually figured out why my query was slow.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356975/mysql-slow-query-waiting-for-query-cache-lock) for answer.  It ended up having nothing to do with network time.  It was a cache size issue.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, absolutely it should run faster.

You probably have made one of these common mistakes:

- You indexed a column, but it wasn't the `date` column.
- You created a multicolumn index but the `date` column is not the first column in the index and therefore cannot be used for this query.
- You clearly remembering adding an index but somehow the index seems to have "vanished" (possibly because you ran the query and it gave an error but you didn't notice the error message).

To find out which it is, run `SHOW CREATE TABLE prvol` and post the output.

---

Another thing you could do to improve the situation is to avoid the use of `SELECT *`. Always select only the columns you need. Even if you think you need all columns you should probably still list them explicitly for safety in case the schema changes in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I actually think that the query is running perfectly fine.

To return 6,882 rows of N-columns (select *) in 0.828 sec is reasonable timing on reasonable hardware.

The network time 21.438 s is just how long it takes to transfer x MB over the network, where `x = bytes per row * 7k`, which could be tens of MB.  But 21s on a network is a bit on the slow side - *but this is not a query issue*.

Comment: Why would the network time be so large when it's all on the same machine?

Comment: A wrong network driver, wrong connection method? Where are you getting the statistics from anyway that includes the network time?

Comment: @Rich I'm using 5.0.0.3272 and it doesn't show network time. You must be connecting to LOCALHOST through a network, even if it is the same machine - hence the network time. I also believe it includes under "network time" any time taken between query completion (reported by MySQL) to data ready within HeidiSQL, which is normally 95% equal to the network component anyway.

Comment: Doing the query from a mysql> prompt in a windows shell gives the same total time - approx 22 seconds.  I think you're right in that it's something strange with the network setup.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this library. It was faster than google's.

```
<script src="https://api.mqcdn.com/sdk/place-search-js/v1.0.0/place-search.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://api.mqcdn.com/sdk/place-search-js/v1.0.0/place-search.css"/>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var ps;
window.onload = function () {
    ps = placeSearch({
        key: 'lYrP4vF3Uk5zgTiGGuEzQGwGIVDGuy24',
        container: document.querySelector('#place-search-input'),
        useDeviceLocation: false,
        collection: [
            'poi',
            'airport',
            'address',
            'adminArea',
        ]
    });
}
```