# MySQL slow query - "Waiting for query cache lock"

Tags: mysql

I am running a simple query on a simple table on the same machine as the server running 5.5.  It is taking 22sec to return ~7000 rows from a 20 million row table.  Upon profiling most of the time is taken up by multiple "Waiting for query cache lock".  What is "Waiting for query cache lock" and why is this query taking so long?  Is it something with the way I set up the server?

Here is the profile (note the time for the operation is actually from the row below as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863447/mysql-slow-sending-data-phase)):

```
mysql> show profile for query 4;
+--------------------------------+----------+
| Status                         | Duration |
+--------------------------------+----------+
| starting                       | 0.000015 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   | 0.000003 |
| checking query cache for query | 0.000045 |
| checking permissions           | 0.000006 |
| Opening tables                 | 0.000027 |
| System lock                    | 0.000007 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   | 0.000032 |
| init                           | 0.000018 |
| optimizing                     | 0.000008 |
| statistics                     | 0.033109 |
| preparing                      | 0.000019 |
| executing                      | 0.000002 |
| Sending data                   | 4.575480 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   | 0.000005 |
| Sending data                   | 5.527728 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   | 0.000005 |
| Sending data                   | 5.743041 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   | 0.000004 |
| Sending data                   | 6.191706 |
| end                            | 0.000007 |
| query end                      | 0.000005 |
| closing tables                 | 0.000028 |
| freeing items                  | 0.000008 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   | 0.000002 |
| freeing items                  | 0.000182 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   | 0.000002 |
| freeing items                  | 0.000002 |
| storing result in query cache  | 0.000004 |
| logging slow query             | 0.000001 |
| logging slow query             | 0.000002 |
| cleaning up                    | 0.000003 |
+--------------------------------+----------+
```

Here is the table:

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE prvol;

"Table","Create Table"
"prvol","CREATE TABLE `prvol` (
  `ticker` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `close` float unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `Index 1` (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1"
```

Here is the query:

```
mysql> select close from prvol where date = '20100203';
```

**EDIT:** After running with SQL_NO_CACHE, all the time is now in the execution.  Could this just be normal for a table this size on a 2.4GHz, 3GB ram machine?

```
+----------------------+-----------+
| Status               | Duration  |
+----------------------+-----------+
| starting             |  0.000052 |
| checking permissions |  0.000007 |
| Opening tables       |  0.000027 |
| System lock          |  0.000008 |
| init                 |  0.000019 |
| optimizing           |  0.000008 |
| statistics           |  0.034766 |
| preparing            |  0.000011 |
| executing            |  0.000002 |
| Sending data         | 22.071324 |
| end                  |  0.000012 |
| query end            |  0.000005 |
| closing tables       |  0.000020 |
| freeing items        |  0.000170 |
| logging slow query   |  0.000001 |
| logging slow query   |  0.000003 |
| cleaning up          |  0.000004 |
+----------------------+-----------+
```

**EDIT:** Include results of explain.

```
mysql> explain extended select cp from prvol where date = '20100208';
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   |rows  | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | prvol | ref  | Index 1       | Index 1 | 4       | const |6868  |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.08 sec)
```

Comment: It looks like it is "Sending data" that takes the majority of the time.

Comment: @Mark: please see the link in the post.  The time seems to be for the elapsed time between the start previous event and the start of the current event.  So the output is a little misleading.  I'm not positive this is true.

Comment: 1) I think you have a problem in the MySQL buffer setup, or with server resources (ram,swap,disk,network). Please kindly move the entire database to a new machine and try this out there. 2) Also note that `Waiting for query cache lock` means that some other thread acquired the cache lock, and prevents this query to write to cache. Try running the query without query cache. `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE close from prvol where date = '20100203';`

Comment: how big is your query cache ? check the following info, especially the recommendations at the bottom of the post http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,406662,406886#msg-406886

Comment: @Pentium10, I reran w/ SQL_NO_CACHE and now all the time is in execution.  It still takes the same time.  I'm thinking that there might be nothing wrong.  It's a big table.

Comment: Please tell us the size in MB of the table you are talking about, and it's possible export the query results to CSV and get the file size.

Comment: @Rich: "It still takes the same time." because Sending time is almost equal in both executions: 4.57+5.52+5.74+6.19=22.02 in first and 22.07 in 2nd execution.

Comment: The table is 1.8GB and the results of the query is about 90kb.

Comment: @ypercube: See the link in the post on how to interpret the output of profile.  I believe the 22sec refers to executing time.

Comment: @Rich C Please if possible try this out on a new machine, maybe your personal machine. It might be just that slow, or they might be some problems with the server as mentioned earlier.

Comment: Can you show us what `EXPLAIN` gives?

Comment: @Rich C You could add an index on `(date,close)` and see if helps.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I solved my slow query problem.  To summarize the problem, it was taking 22sec to query 7000 rows from a 20mln row, 1.7GB indexed table.  The problem was that the cache was too small and the query had to go to disk for every query.  I would think the disk access would be faster than what I was seeing because I was going off an indexed column so the amount of data read off disk should have been small.  But I'm guessing there is a lot of overhead with accessing the InnoDB storage on disk.

Once I set `innodb_buffer_pool_size=1024M` in the my.ini file, the initial query would take a long time, but all subsequent queries would finish in under a second.

Unfortunately, the profiling didn't really help.

Comment: Did you increase or decrease it?

Comment: I increased it.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me too!

Answer (score 12):

This is a known problem with MySQL. It's really well described here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20160129162137/http://www.psce.com/blog/kb/how-query-cache-can-cause-performance-problems/

Query cache can help you a lot but at the same time it can become a bottleneck.