# Mysql cache is my headache

Tags: mysql, mysql5, mysql-5.5

This is my status of query cache

```
SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Qcache%';
+-------------------------+------------+
| Variable_name           | Value      |
+-------------------------+------------+
| Qcache_free_blocks      | 33981      |
| Qcache_free_memory      | 166966128  |
| Qcache_hits             | 1345257151 |
| Qcache_inserts          | 742505272  |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes    | 232069766  |
| Qcache_not_cached       | 648660189  |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache | 80929      |
| Qcache_total_blocks     | 196034     |
```

I am getting too many connection and 80% queries are stucked in " 0 | Waiting for query cache lock".
I am thinking to Disable the query cache completely.

Set:
query_cache_type=0
query_cache_size=0

But before than can i calculate how many queries are hitting the cache and how many not ? so that i can give stronger case for the smae

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356975/mysql-slow-query-waiting-for-query-cache-lock) where the user changed `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to an appropriate number to solve the problem

Comment: @zedfoxus i have set this as 30GB, please suggest something else