# Requests to MariaDB sometimes are too slow

Tags: mariadb

A have fast VDS with MariaDB. All working good and fast for me. But some times i see "long" requests in logs.

For ex: very small (~100 records) table Account (InnoDB). Avg.load is 10-20 req/sec.

1-4 times per day such (and other insert/update/delete to another tables) requests takes too long time:

This example - 13 sec!!!

```
[query] => UPDATE Account SET ?v WHERE aID=?i
[values] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [NTS] => 20200903150306
                [RNo] => RNo+1
                [RBlock] => 57942375
            )

        [1] => 40
    )

[result] => 1
[profile] => Array
    (
        [starting] => 0.000019
        [checking permissions] => 0.000003
        [Opening tables] => 0.000006
        [After opening tables] => 0.000003
        [System lock] => 0.000002
        [Table lock] => 0.000002
        [After table lock] => 0.000002
        [init] => 0.000023
        [Updating] => 0.000038
        [end] => 0.002961
        [Waiting for query cache lock] => 13.343287
        [query end] => 0.056900
        [closing tables] => 0.000011
        [freeing items] => 0.000006
        [updating status] => 0.000011
        [cleaning up] => 0.000004
    )
```

Table have primary index on field aID
[profile] is profile info of request

What does [Waiting for query cache lock] mean?
Why its so long?

Where can I find info about each stage?

Comment: Possible duplicate? [MySQL slow query - "Waiting for query cache lock"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356975/mysql-slow-query-waiting-for-query-cache-lock)

Comment: Where did that output come from?  Especially with "query" misspelled.

Answer (score 1):

? Waiting for query cache lock

Turn off the query cache:

```
query_cache_size = 0
query_cache_type = 0
```

The "Query Cache" is an optimization that is rarely useful.  It provides resultsets without re-evaluating the query when several criteria are met.

13 seconds is a huge amount of time; I can't explain that.

What Engine are you using?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE ..`